# parsing conditional string against dataset

Tags: parsing, compilation, conditional-statements, string-matching, interpretation

I have a dataset/array for example: `['b', 'd', 'e']`

and i have a condition from a external source as string, for example:

`((a)/(b)&(d)&NOT(c))` `((a/b/c/((d)&(e)))&NOT(f/g/h))` `(d&t)&NOT(u)`

*/ means OR       & means AND*

My goal is to match my array against this condition but i just don't have any idea
what language/framework or approach is most suitable for this use-case.

something in `php` would be nice but i appreciate every help you can give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research i was able to find a package with which i was able to get it working:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html